# Send email if a cell value matches

Tags: excel, power-automate

I'm trying to send an email based on excel sheet cell value, for example IF CELL says YES, copy that row data and send email.
I have tried using trigger FOR A SELECTED ROW and action SEND AN EMAIL which does work but I'm looking a way to email only certain row data based the cell value.

[image]

Comment: Did you solve your issue?

Answer (score 0):

As you get hold of the cell using `For a selected row` you can use any value of the row itself to do whatever you want to, as below.
On the "Condition" use the cell you want to to check - remember that this cell will be the same for every iteration you do, if that is the case.

[image]

One the e-mail body section, you can select the fields you want to use. Optionally, you can use a `Compose` action before to combine all the info in one "variable" and put it inside the body itself.
[image]